# My SQL query is only returning children I need the parent aswell

Tags: sql, mysql

My sql query is only returning the children of the parent I need it to return the parent as well,

```
public function getNav($cat,$subcat){
    //gets all sub categories for a specific category
    if(!$this->checkValue($cat)) return false;  //checks data

    $query = false;
    if($cat=='NULL'){
        $sql = "SELECT itemID, title, parent, url, description, image 
                FROM p_cat 
                WHERE deleted = 0
                AND parent is NULL
                ORDER BY position;";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql) or die($this->db->error);
    }else{
        //die($cat);
        $sql = "SET @parent = (SELECT c.itemID FROM p_cat c WHERE url = '".$this->sql($cat)."' AND deleted = 0);

                SELECT c1.itemID, c1.title, c1.parent, c1.url, c1.description, c1.image, (SELECT c2.url FROM p_cat c2 WHERE c2.itemID = c1.parent LIMIT 1) as parentUrl
                FROM p_cat c1
                WHERE c1.deleted = 0
                AND c1.parent = @parent
                ORDER BY c1.position;";
        $query = $this->db->multi_query($sql) or die($this->db->error);
        $this->db->store_result(); $this->db->next_result();
        $query = $this->db->store_result();
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Just make sure on line 6 that you really want to be comparing against a string whose value happens to be 'NULL' rather than a NULL value. Possible bug or confusion there. Not directly related to the question, I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be:

```
"SET @parent = (SELECT c.itemID FROM p_cat c WHERE url = '".$this->sql($cat)."' AND deleted = 0);

                SELECT c1.itemID, c1.title, c1.parent, c1.url, c1.description, c1.image, (SELECT c2.url FROM p_cat c2 WHERE c2.itemID = c1.parent LIMIT 1) as parentUrl
                FROM p_cat c1
                WHERE c1.deleted = 0
                AND (c1.parent = @parent OR c1.itemID = @parent)
                ORDER BY c1.position;"
```

Comment: all parents? i think add OR c1.parent IS NULL

Answer (score 0):

Just join the p_cat table back to itself:

```
SELECT c1.itemID, c1.title, c1.parent, c1.url, c1.description, c1.image
    , parents.itemID, parents.parent, parents.url, parents.description, parents.image,
FROM p_cat c1
    Inner Join p_cat parents
        On parents.id = C1.parent
WHERE c1.deleted = 0
    AND c1.parent = @parent
ORDER BY c1.position
```